# Find census tracks under poly in KML file

Tags: kml, google-earth, census

Using Google Earth, I have loaded all of the census tracts in my state (denoted in the image as thin blue lines) via a FCC provided KML file. I've also added a KML file that displays a circle.

What I want to do, is programmatically determine which census tracts lie inside the circle.

I really can't think of where to start to do this, meaning which data I need to compare to make a match. I'd love a gentle shove in the right direction.

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Google Earth will do a good job for visualizing these datasets, it does not have the GIS/analysis tools needed to do what you're asking for.  You probably need a Clip or Intersect function. One tool you can use is QGIS, the free, open-source GIS software, though be aware that it's rather complex and there's quite a learning curve for importing data, making sure it's ready to analyze (correct projections, etc.) and then producing the desired result.  Depending on what tools and platforms you know, there may be other options, like gdal for command-line and programatic processing of GIS datasets.

Comment: While I will probably go with a scripted solution like this: https://github.com/tparkin/Google-Maps-Point-in-Polygon
Your answer pointed me in the right direction. 
Thanks.